# ${\sqrt{2x+1}=1+\sqrt{x}}$ — I dont know if the solution is correct. Help?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> ${\sqrt{2x+1}=1+\sqrt{x}}$
>   ${2x+1=1+2\sqrt{x}+x}$
>   ${x=2\sqrt{x}}$
>   ${x*\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}=2}$
>   ${\sqrt{x}=2}$
>   ${x=4}$

Comment: Title looks like "$\sqrt{2x+1}=1+\sqrt{x}i$", with complex number $i$...

Comment: I'd suggest redoing the title.  I read that as "$\sqrt{2x + 1} = 1 + \sqrt{x}$ I don't know if it's true" and my first that was "Of course, it's not true! What a dumb question!"  Perhaps, "I don't know if my solution is correct".

Comment: Well, $x\big(\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}\big) = \frac{x^1}{x^{1/2}} = x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}$. Therefore, if the fraction is equal to $2$, then $\sqrt{x} = 2$ so I see no problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You divided  $x^{\frac12}$ without checking whether $x=0$ is a solution.  When using division to solve an equation, you get only solutions where the divisor isn't zero, so be sure to separately check cases where the divisor is zero.

Answer (score 4):

The fourth step is not correct. You may rather write
$$
x=2\sqrt{x}
$$ $$
x-2\sqrt{x}=0
$$$$
\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}-2\right)=0
$$
$$
\sqrt{x}=0 \quad \text{or} \quad 
\sqrt{x}-2=0
$$ giving easily 
$$x=0, \qquad x=4
$$ as solutions.

Answer (score 4):

it must be $$x\geq 0$$ after squaring we get
$$x=2\sqrt{x}$$
squaring again we obtain $$x(x-4)=0$$ thus we get $$x=0$$ or $$x=4$$ which are indeed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide by $\sqrt{x}$, you are assuming something. This assumption discards another valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are mostly correct but there are two conditions you didn't take into account which you should have.

$\sqrt{2x + 1}=1+\sqrt{x}$  Note, this implies $2x + 1 \ge 0$ i.e $x \ge -\frac 12$.

$2x +1 = 1 + 2\sqrt{x} + x$  Now, we have "lost" that assumption.  It is possible that we will end up with some extraneous answers where $x < -\frac 12$.  As it turns out that isn't an issue and it doesn't happen but it could have. (As we still have $\sqrt{x}$ that implies $x \ge 0$ so $x < -\frac 12$ is impossible).

$x = 2\sqrt{x}$

$x/x^{1/2} = 2$ Here you divided by $x^{1/2}$ in the assumption $x^{1/2} \ne 0$.  You can not make that assumption.  You must consider the possibility that $x^{1/2}$.

So say: Case 1: If $\sqrt{x} = 0$, then $x= 0$ and we have $0 = 2\sqrt{0}$ which consistent so $x = 0$ is a possible answer.

But if $\sqrt{x} \ne 0$ then

$x/x^{1/2} = 2$

$x^{1/2} = 2$

$x =4$

So $x=4$ is the only other  possible solution .  So $x = 0$ or $x = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

For more information try [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%5Csqrt%7B2x%2B1%7D%3D1%2B%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%7D).

**As for the solution:**

$x=2\sqrt{x}$

$x-2\sqrt{x}=0$

$\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt{x}-2\right)=0$

$\sqrt{x}=0 \quad \text{or} \quad 
\sqrt{x}-2=0$

We get:

$x=0, \qquad x=4$ as solutions.

**Understood:**   you made the mistake in the 4th line

Comment: We do not recommend you use all-caps, as it is usually very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the omission of the solution $0,$ there's an important point here that I think some of the other answers are glossing over.  Your method does not show that $0$ and $4$ are solutions — what it shows is that no number other than $0$ or $4$ is a solution.  You still need to check that $0$ and $4$ actually work.  (In this case, they do, but in some similar problems, you can get spurious solutions in addition to the actual solutions.)

Here's a complete argument:

If $${\sqrt{2x+1}=1+\sqrt{x}},$$ then deduce $$x=2\sqrt{x}$$ just as you did. Square both sides to get $$x^2=4x.$$ It follows that either (a) $x=0$ or (b) you can divide both sides by $x$ to get $x=4.$

At this point, all we have shown is that *if* $x$ is a solution, *then* $x$ must equal either $0$ or $4.$ So $0$ and $4$ are the only two possibilities for a solution.  You still need to check out each one of these possible solutions individually:

$${\sqrt{2\cdot 0+1}=1=1+\sqrt{0}}$$

and

$${\sqrt{2\cdot 4+1}=3=1+\sqrt{4}},$$

so in fact both $0$ and $4$ *are* solutions (and so they're the only solutions, since we already know that any solution has to be either $0$ or $4).$